# How to say "After +Verb" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, grammar, conversation

How to say "After +Verb" in daily conversation?

For example:

"After eating my candy, I will go there".

"After he saw you were coming, he left".

"After she found the book, she called me".

etc.

So the focus here is the "After" word. I know 后 is usually used for this case. But I wonder whether there are other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give the example of `very natural` translation：

"After eating my candy, I will go there".

我吃完糖就走。

"After he saw you were coming, he left".

他看到你来了之后就走了。

"After she found the book, she called me".

她找到这本书后叫了我。

But, there is difference between `After` and `后`. Chinese will add another word to explain the time accurately, for example , the `就` shows I will do it immediately after that.In some case , cause `就` explain the causation between two things, so the `后` can be omitted, just like the first translated sentence.

Answer (score 3):

'After' can be expressed with 以后 placed after the clause:

吃完糖果以后，我去那里。

The second sentence can be translated using an 'after', e.g.:

他看到你来以后，他离开了。But it would sound 'more natural' if you dropped it:

他看到你来，就离开了。

Comment: Can I say like this: **我吃了糖果，我去那边。**, **他看到了你，他直接走。** ?

Comment: @suud Repetition of the subject seems redundant and the connection between the clauses (1st half, 2nd half) is not that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

（somewhat intelligent） use of iciba translate will provide the answer

在…以后， can be shortened to 。。。后

e。g。 在吃我的糖果以后，我会去那里，吃我的糖果后，我会去那里

other possibilities exist，especially if something happens immediately after

当他看到你来了，他离开了 （as he saw you were coming he left）

Comment: '在吃我的糖果以后' sounds more than odd me.

Comment: The single 后 at back like in 吃我的糖果后 sounds awkward to say. And I feel 以后 is like saying "Someday...". Is there other alternative?

Comment: iciba  once 6. CONJ-SUBORD 一旦…（就…); 一…（就…） If something happens once another thing has happened, it happens immediately afterwards.  ：一旦吃（完）我的糖果，我就会去那里

Comment: from own reading experience this user would of course have suggested  。。。以后，。。。之后， but following own suggestion against own better judgment copied result from iciba。 照自己阅读经验本使用者（用户）的建议当然应该是 。。。以后，。。。之后，但是遵循自己的建议并违背自己的判断就抄袭爱词霸的翻译了